# How to remove an electrical cord strain relief bushing / collar?

Tags: electrical, appliances, garbage-disposal, cord-and-plug, extension

How does one remove an electrical cord strain relief bushing/collar like this one:

[image: electrical cord strain relief bushing/collar]
Source: https://www.centurytool.net/100385_Robinair_Power_Cord_Strain_Relief_p/ro100385.htm

[This is the spec sheet](https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/mm5/graphics/F04/SR3W-1.pdf) for a nearly identical strain relief bushing.

Ideally, I would like to remove it so it can be reused, if that's possible.

The existing one is attached to a garbage disposal (disposer), so there is no easy access the inside of the unit.  I seem to recall there is a special type of pliers that can be used for this task, but I would prefer not to have to go out and buy yet another tool for this simple task.

After more searching, I found that [this amazing gentleman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mI2srvj0yzA) has a special set of pliers for the task, but I don't have those pliers, and I couldn't find any place near me that sells them.

Comment: Yes, I have used a special tool (from Heyco); but, it is for designed for inserting. It *might* help remove the strain relief, but no guarantees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without access to the inside wall, you have quite a challenge ahead. I've removed quite a few of these but from the inside, by pressing down with a screwdriver on the top "latch" while simultaneously pulling from the outside.

In your situation, you have to compress the outer portion of the latch, ostensibly to get it below the hole in the wall, while pulling. We've learned to not pull on wiring, due to the damage that can result, but one might surmise that aspect is of low importance.

This allows you to compress the outer portion of the latch with pliers that provide for a reasonable grip. The outward force has to be applied, but the pliers will slip. Provide the outward force by applying gradual pull on the wiring. Wiggling the pliers in the vertical plane may also help to release the detent built into the assembly. Ensure that the pliers are compressing only the smaller movable part with one jaw and the entirety of the grommet on the opposite side.

Comment: Thanks Fred.  Upvoted.  I added a link to a good video that I just found, and the gentleman in the video is basically doing exactly what you recommended, but with a special set of pliers.  I don't have those pliers, but I think I'm going to try your advice and see if I can get it out.  I do have a hunch that wire cutters are going to end this job. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Fred.  Everything went exactly as you wrote.  It wasn't easy, but job done and all parts salvaged to use on another project.

Comment: "Oh, yeah, unhook the wires!" Great bit of dialog in the video. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I loved that bit of dialog in the video too.  Big smile on that line.